# React Native not re-rendering Listview

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux

So I am new to `React Native` and I am building this app with `redux` and `react-navigation`. Here's the problem:

I am fetching records from API, things were working fine. While I fetch records there's a `Loading` icon then after that the `Listview` display the records, then when there are no records I display a `No record found.` `Text`. Then suddenly the records just stop displaying, the `Loading` icon just keep on displaying when there are records but when there's no record the `Text` displays.

What could have caused this bug? I am using `Expo` so I print to console the fetched records and there are records. Also after the data get fetched I put a `console.log` in `render` function and it is called which means it just don't render the `Listview`.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

So i've used `FlatList` as suggested below and i've found that the `item` passed from `FlatList` is undefined which is again strange cause when I print the data I passed on the list it has contents. Here is my current code:

MyFlatlist

```
return <FlatList
  data={data} //an array of objects
  renderItem={this._renderItem} //console prints undefined
/>

//I also tried
return <FlatList
  data={data} //an array of objects
  renderItem={({item}) => this._renderItem(item)} //I think this doesn't call the method cause it doesn't print anything on the console.
/>
```

MyRenderItem

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => {
  console.log(item)
}
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

So there were two factors that caused this problem, first the API where I get my data changed which result to fields that I access in my view isn't there anymore, `React Native` see this as error and as a result the rendering stops without an error msg which is why it is hard to detect. Second, when I used `FlatList`, the per item sent to the renderItem function is also under an object which has a property `item` that contains the actual data so the rendering stops again.

This is fixed now as far as my setup is concerned. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Show us some code please, there's a lot of different things that could be wrong.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I couldn't show any code, assuming everything is in place, cause as i've said it just suddenly didn't work I didn't even touch the code, what are other factors that could affect this?

Comment: Ah so it was working then it stopped without any changes? I haven't really used expo but maybe try closing everything and stop any packagers running and try running it again.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that and restarted the PC, still the same.

Comment: Use FlatList instead, It solves this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve come across the ListView not re-rendering before.

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html):

> The rowHasChanged function provided to the data source tells the ListView if it needs to re-render a row because the source data has changed - see [ListViewDataSource](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html) for more details.

ListView was DEPRECATED though. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html. Try using [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) or [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html). More about it from this [article](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html).

Comment: Hi, still wasn't successful, i've edited my question though.

Comment: Try the handle from the docs? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html
`<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>`

Comment: I updated my question again, it was my fault after all. Sorry for the troubles :)